# Extract text until second to last occurrence from string

Tags: javascript

How do I extract the text from the beginning until (not including) the second to last occurrence of
a charachter (":" in this case) from a string? Preferably without using regex.

**Examples:**

"urn:riv:intygsbestallning:certificate:order:RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1" should become "RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1"

"urn:riv:itinfra:tp:PingResponder:1" should become "PingResponder:1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
str = 'urn:riv:intygsbestallning:certificate:order:RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1'

split_array = str.split(':')
ans = split_array.splice(-2).join(':')

console.log('ans', ans)

cut_off_part = split_array.join(':') + ':'
console.log('cut_off part', cut_off_part)
```

Another way of doing the same:

```js
str = 'urn:riv:intygsbestallning:certificate:order:RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1'

ans = str.split(':').splice(-2).join(':')
console.log("answer", ans)

cutoff_part = str.substr(0, str.length - ans.length)
console.log("cut_off_part", cutoff_part)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I access the part that was "cut off"?

Comment: Yes sure, let me update my answer

Comment: @RawlandHustle I have updated my answer for the cut-off part as well. Please upvote and accept if you find the answer helpful and it solved your query.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Comment: @RawlandHustle There are many ways to do it. I am adding one more way to do it. Thanks for upvoting and accepting.

Answer (score 1):

with `split` function you can parse your string returning an array of the tokens separated from the string in the parameter of `split` and later you can concatenate last two items in the array

```js
let x = "urn:riv:intygsbestallning:certificate:order:RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1";

let result = x.split(":");
let yourTextResult = `${result[result.length-2]}:${result[result.length-1]}`;
console.log(yourTextResult );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data1 = "urn:riv:intygsbestallning:certificate:order:RequestPerformerForAssessmentResponder:1";
const data2 = "urn:riv:itinfra:tp:PingResponder:1"

const arr = data1.split(':');
console.log(arr.splice(arr.length-2,arr.length).join(':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, I'm very sure that it is not the best code, but I am sure that you can improve it having it as a base, I hope it will be useful to you

```
var mainString = "urn:riv:itinfra:tp:PingResponder:1"
var inverseString = reverseString(mainString)
var result = getFinalString(inverseString)
console.log(result)
function reverseString(str){
    return str.split('').reverse().join('')
}
function getFinalString(str){
    var stringAux = str.split(':')
    if(stringAux.length>=2){
        finalString=reverseString(stringAux[0]+':'+stringAux[1])
        return finalString
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.